# stdout not compile-time constant

Tags: c

The title says it all. Why is `stdout` not compile-time constant? Why is this fine

```
int main() {
  const FILE *fp = stdout;
}
```

but not

```
const FILE *fp = stdout;
int main() {
}
```

Shouldn't both fail, if its not compile-time constant?

Say I'm writing a logging util and I want to make stdout my default output stream, how can I do that (without initial setup function call)

```
struct config {
  FILE *this_should_be_stdout;
};
struct config conf = {
  .this_should_be_stdout = stdout
}
```

Comment: That variable `fp` probably has no business at file scope anyway. Or if it must be there for some reason, the quick & dirty work-around would be (in the .c file) to `#define fp stdout`.

Comment: @Lundin so it's considered bad practice anyways? Should I store the file descriptor or what would be the clean way?

Comment: You could store it in your struct like you seem to have intended. That doesn't mean it has to be set during initialization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is correct behaviour, since `stdout` is *not* a constant. The reason it works inside `main` is that the `stdout` variable is effectively "brought into existence" during the start-up of `main`. By that, I mean the variable itself exists but the actual connection to a stream (initialisation) happens at some point before `main` starts executing.

The reason why this is flagged as an error can be seen in `C17 6.7.9 Initialization §4`:

> All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static or thread storage duration shall be constant expressions or string literal.

Since `stdout` is neither of those things, and variables at file level are static storage duration, the former cannot be used to initialise the latter.

Answer (score 3):

Inside the function it's automatic, but outside it's static. You will run into the same problem inside the function with `static const FILE *fp = stdout;`. The compiler is, in fact, being consistent.

As to why, that's what the standard says, presumably to make life easier on C compilers so that they don't have execute C code at compile time. I am not aware of a workaround that does not require code that sets the global variable. I suppose you could use a file descriptor, an `int` instead of a `FILE *`, and have `const int fd = 1;`, which goes to `stdout`.

Answer (score 2):

Because only *constant* expressions can be used to initialize variables that have file scope, per the [(draft) C11's **6.7.9 Initialization**, paragraph 4](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p4):

> All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static or thread storage duration shall be constant expressions or string literals.

Constant expressions are limited by [**6.6 Constant expressions**, paragraph 3](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.6p3):

> Constant expressions shall not contain assignment, increment, decrement, function-call, or comma operators ...

`stdout` is not required to be a **constant** expression per the [7.21.1 Introduction](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.1)

> **7.21.1 Introduction**
>
> 1 The header <stdio.h> defines several macros, and declares three
> types and many functions for performing input and output.
>
> ...
>
> 3 The macros are ...
>
> ...
>
> ```
>      stderr
>      stdin
>      stdout
> ```
>
> which are expressions of type ''pointer to FILE'' that point to the
> FILE objects associated, respectively, with the standard error, input,
> and output streams.

Note that `stdout` is an *expressions of type ''pointer to FILE''*, and that it is **not** required to be a "constant expression".

On your system, `stdout` likely involves a function call or some other code that requires run-time evaluation.

Answer (score 2):

> Shouldn't both fail, if its not compile-time constant?

No, initialization of ***automatic storage duration*** objects does not require constant expressions.

```
struct config {
  FILE *this_should_be_stdout;
};

struct config conf;

int any_of_your_util_functions(int x)
{
    if(!conf.this_should_be_stdout) conf.this_should_be_stdout = stdout;
    /* ... */
}
```

or if your compiler has constructor externsion (like GCC)

```
void __attribute__((constructor)) myinit(void)
{
     conf.this_should_be_stdout = stdout;
}
```